# Automatically bold the entire text in PDF file

Tags: pdf, fonts

I received a set of large pdf files (> 1000 pages each), and I would like to "automatically" bold the entire text in these files (in order to perform OCR process later).

I can do this task manually, page by page, through Adobe Acrobat Pro. But I wonder if it can be done automatically through a tool or by writing a piece of code ?

P.S.: Those pdf files are private and it's not allowable to upload them to an online service (if such service exists!)

Comment: I've no exact solution, but an idea would be to convert the pages to single images, with gimp for example. And as a second step to process these images. For example with https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Answer (score 0):

There is (to the best of my knowledge) no good tool for doing this in a way that is 100% failsafe.

The problem is that PDF is not an easy format. Think of it more as a container of instructions. Words don't appear in the document as consecutive bytes. They appear as instructions like:

1. place the cursor at position 10, 50
2. set font to Times New Roman, size 10
3. Draw the string "H"
4. Go to position 14, 50
5. Draw the string "e"
6. etc

If you want to bold the text you'd run into various problems.

- bolding text might make it no longer fit the line, which means you need to re-layout the page. Re-layouting a page is insanely hard. You need to know which characters belong together, what makes a paragraph, what makes a title, etc. Otherwise you can not sensibly move content around.
- bolding the text means you need to know what text is already bold. That's also non-trivial. Fonts have a flag that enables readers to know whether they are bold. But the property "being bold" can also be realized in other ways. So whatever tool you're using would need to be able to accurately determine whether a given glyph is bold, or simply some artistic slightly bolder rendition of a character in a normal font.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that jumps out to me is that you want to do this "*in order to perform OCR process later*". Based on that, it would seem your real goal isn't having a bunch of boldface text—your goal is to be able to better perform OCR on this set of documents.

If that's true, some things to keep in mind:

- Boldfacing text won't necessarily make it more legible to an OCR process—in fact, in some cases it can make it *less* legible. (There is also no automated way to determine what effect it will have on a given page of text.)
- PDFs that contain text (as opposed to just images of pages of text) store the text digitally in a way that can be extracted by a PDF processing app. Text you extract this way will nearly always be more accurate than what you get from an OCR process.
- If these *are* 'image PDFs' full of images of pages of text, you're not going to be able to easily boldface that text in the first place, any more than you can change the text in a snapshot of a road sign. (Indeed, you'd have to OCR it first just to be able to boldface it.)
- If you want to print these PDFs so that they can be scanned and OCR'd later, you really ought to look into ways to make them available electronically.

In short, rather than focusing on how to make thousands of pages of text boldface, I'd suggest stepping back and looking at what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Could you please give me some examples of "PDF processing apps" ?